# Removing .asmx extension from web service URL

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I've written an ASP.NET web service. The web service is used via HTTP GET. I'd like the URL to not contain .asmx extension.
Right now, the URL looks like http://localhost:1200/Service1.asmx 
I'd like it to be http://localhost:1200/Service1.

I've tried creating handler mappings in IIS 7.5 but all in vain. Does anyone have a step by step guide on how this can be done ?

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

I feel rather than creating your handler read below mentioned articles and start creating REST services in .NET.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529